# how to get user identities having isDeleted false in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I tried to get users having `isDeleted==false` but I am getting still all users. What did I do wrong?

**My try**

```
 var users = await _userManager.Users.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted==false).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working after building a project.